# Are the following graphs isomorphic?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

[image: The two graphs.]

The graphs have different cycle lengths. So can they be considered as not isomorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An isomorphism would map a cycle to a cycle of the same length, so the fact that one graph has triangles ($3$-cycles) and the other one doesn't implies that the graphs are not isomorphic.